# Whatever item in a table is clicked, put that value on a hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I need whatever item clicked on a table to be captured and putted in a hidden input.
This is as far as I got:

```js
var $rows = $('#table tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
$('td').click(function() {
    var txt = $('td:first-child').text();
    $('#tipo').val(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="rotulo">Filtrar:</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="rotulo" id="search">
</div>
<table class="table" id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>1st Value</td>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
        <td>2nd Value </td>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
        <td>3rd Value </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
<input type="text" id="tipo" value="">
```

The problem is, whatever value I click, many items in the table are selected, even when this first item is hidden.
Jquery is being used.

Comment: Thanks stackErr, I have editted my question. Now some selection is being made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`td:first-child` is selecting the first child td, that's why you are always getting the first element.

The clicked element text can be retrieved by using `$(this).text()`

Comment: Thanks! I was so close... urgently got to take a Js course.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```
$('td').click(function() {
  var txt = $('.table').find('td:visible:first').text();
  $('#tipo').val(txt);
});
```

It will find the first visible element in the table and outputs its text.

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2hyerc5v/1/).